# How do i access another table using another tables data im accessing with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, ejs

Okay so, I'm displaying a friends table with Sequelize in Nodejs, Everything goes to plan but I run into a problem. For the friends table i store the user ids and then access the user data with those ids then display it onto ejs. I want to access another table using the current tables data.

Heres the code to access the Friends table, I made it a function so i can access it from ejs

```
    let getFriends = async (id) => {
  const project = await database.Friends.findAndCountAll({ where: { fid: id } });
  return project.rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access another table using include.
new code will be

```
let getFriends = async (id) => {
  const project = await database.Friends.findAndCountAll({ where: { fid: id },
include:[{
model:model.User,as:'user'}]
 });
return project;
  
}
```

Comment: How could  i access the specific user data with data from friends using that method?